# Complex SQL Query to refer the previous record

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a requirement as below, Need your help.

I have a table:

```
name desig
A   manager
B   employee
C   employee
D   employee
E   employee
F   manager
G   employee
```

I need to get the result as:

```
emp manager
A null
B A
C A
D A
E A
F null
G F
```

Below are the scripts i have developed for your convenience:

```
create table int2 (name varchar(10), desig varchar(10));

insert into int2 values ('A','manager');
insert into int2 values ('B','employee');
insert into int2 values ('C','employee');
insert into int2 values ('D','employee');
insert into int2 values ('E','employee');
insert into int2 values ('F','manager');
insert into int2 values ('G','employee');

commit;
```

I tried running the below query but of no help

```
with test as (
      select a.* , rownum rn from int2 a
     )
select a.name, a.desig
from test a, test b
where a.rn = b.rn+1
    and a.desig !=b.desig;
```

Comment: would it be possible to add one more column to the said table? preferably there must be something to reference which manager the employee belongs to.

Comment: I hope your table has _something_ that allows you to sort it deterministically in the order you've show, otherwise you're doomed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key here is to classify employees into groups. Starting from the first occurrence of manager to the next occurrence, all the employees are classified into the same group. All the employees of a group will have the same manager.

This can be done using the `sum` window function. Run the inner query alone to see how the groups are assigned. Thereafter the code to get the manager for each group is intuitive.

```
select name,case when desig='manager' then null 
            else max(case when desig='manager' then name end) over(partition by grp) end as mgr
from (select i.*
      ,sum(case when desig='manager' then 1 else 0 end) over(order by name) as grp
      from int2 i
     ) x
```

[`Sample Demo`](http://rextester.com/KKJZH24093)

Comment: Thank you very much, its working and i got the technicality behind the query